# problem in parsing html page

Tags: html, parsing

i have a problem in a parsing one html page.
the link of the page is http://www.symmetricom.com/resources/glossary/telecommunications-glossary/
now if i take the node strong that contains the name of the word it works great but if i want to take the definition that is contained in node br it doesn't work. i use html cleaner to clean the code of web page. please help me it's very important

Comment: What are you using to parse the page? Also show some code. And you're aware that you're probably not supposed to scrape that page?

Answer (score 0):

The description text is outside the `<br>` tag, `<br>` is line braek tag. How do you parse this HTML, and why you are cleaning code?

Comment: a ok! thanks for the quick reply. i take all the strong nodes in this way: 
TagNode Elements[] = rootNode.getElementsByName("strong", true);
  for (int i = 0; i < Elements.length; i++) {
 lista.add(Elements[i].getText().toString().toLowerCase());
}

Comment: i clean tha code because i try to parse the html page with sax library but i receive errors and in this way it works

Comment: Try to use Python + BeautifulSoup, the documentation is perfect for BeautifulSoup.

Comment: sorry but i have never used python! is there a way to do with java and library that i use?